# Sum up multiple values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following SQL code to get the count of reservation for each quater of the year:

```
SELECT 
    Year, 
    ISNULL(QPivot.[1],0) As [Quater 1], 
    ISNULL(QPivot.[2],0) As [Quater 2], 
    ISNULL(QPivot.[3],0) As [Quater 3], 
    ISNULL(QPivot.[4],0) As [Quater 4] 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         YEAR(checkInDate) [Year], 
         DATEPART(QUARTER, checkInDate) [Quarter], 
         COUNT(1) [Reservation Count] 
     FROM 
         ReservationRoom  
     GROUP BY 
         YEAR(checkInDate), DATEPART(QUARTER, checkInDate)) AS QuarterlyData 
PIVOT(SUM([Reservation Count]) 
FOR QUARTER IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS QPivot
```

This is the results I got from that query:

[[image: my result]

But now I want to add in one column `[Total]` which sum up all the values of all quarters for the year. For example year 2015 is 1 and 2016 is 8.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please tag dbms product used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: @jarlh Is there a "not MySQL" tag?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I don't think that's enough in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally find pivot queries a bit hard to read. All that your query does is have a result row per year (so group by year) and count quarters and total (so have some count expressions). The query can easily be written as:

```
select 
  year(checkindate) as year, 
  count(case when datepart(quarter, checkindate) = 1 then 1 end) as q1,
  count(case when datepart(quarter, checkindate) = 2 then 1 end) as q2,
  count(case when datepart(quarter, checkindate) = 3 then 1 end) as q3,
  count(case when datepart(quarter, checkindate) = 4 then 1 end) as q4,
  count(*) as total
from reservationroom  
group by year(checkindate)
order by year(checkindate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the four quarters together:

```
SELECT t.Year, t.[Quarter 1], t.[Quarter 2], t.[Quarter 3], t.[Quarter 4],
    (t.[Quarter 1] + t.[Quarter 2] + t.[Quarter 3] + t.[Quarter 4]) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT Year, ISNULL(QPivot.[1],0) As [Quater 1], ISNULL(QPivot.[2],0) As [Quater 2],
        ISNULL(QPivot.[3],0) As [Quater 3], ISNULL(QPivot.[4],0) As [Quater 4],
    FROM
    (
        SELECT YEAR(checkInDate) [Year], DATEPART(QUARTER, checkInDate) [Quarter], COUNT(1) [Reservation Count] 
        FROM ReservationRoom  
        GROUP BY YEAR(checkInDate), DATEPART(QUARTER,checkInDate)) AS QuarterlyData
        PIVOT( SUM([Reservation Count]) 
        FOR QUARTER IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) AS QPivot
) t
```

Comment: thanks for your help..but im getting this  'QPivot.Year' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I can suggest that you try wrapping this query and selecting out the year, quarters, and total.